# GridView scrolling stuttering

Tags: android, image, gridview, bitmap

I have a problem with my image adapter I think.. Whenether I scroll trough the gridview it stutters badly. I think I overlooked something in my code but i cant figure it out.

My image adapter code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        context = c;
    }

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return logoCount;
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item---
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        Drawable drawable = null;
        switch(GetLogoStatus(position)) {
            case 1:
                drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.check);
                break;
            case 2:
                drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.tipsused);
                break;
            case 3:
                drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.cross);
                break;
        }
        final Bitmap largeImage = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        final Drawable logoDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, GetImage(position));
        Bitmap smallImage = ((BitmapDrawable) logoDrawable).getBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(largeImage);

        float ratioBitmap = (float) smallImage.getWidth() / (float) smallImage.getHeight();
        float ratioMax = (float) largeImage.getWidth() / (float) largeImage.getHeight();
        int finalWidth = largeImage.getWidth();
        int finalHeight = largeImage.getHeight();
        if (ratioMax > 1) {
            finalWidth = (int) ((float)largeImage.getHeight() * ratioBitmap);
        } else {
            finalHeight = (int) ((float)largeImage.getWidth() / ratioBitmap);
        }
        smallImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(smallImage, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);

        int startX= (canvas.getWidth()-smallImage.getWidth())/2;
        int startY=(canvas.getHeight()-smallImage.getHeight())/2;
        canvas.drawBitmap(smallImage,startX, startY, null);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(largeImage);

        //imageView.setImageResource(GetImage(position));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me out:)

Comment: Looks like you're doing an awful lot of scaling and such on the main thread, which could very well contribute. You could offload the work onto another thread (being careful that references still exist in the mean time), or you can give the Picasso library a shot which handles a lot of that for you.

Comment: Beyond that, use tools like Traceview to determine where you are spending your time. My guess is that you're dying due to due much garbage collection, as you are creating a lot of garbage with each row. Instead of creating a bunch of bitmaps, create your own subclass of `View` that does your scaling and rendering.

Comment: @ReinS what parts of the code should I put in a thread for better performance?

Comment: @CommonsWare what do you mean with a subclass?

Comment: Pretty much what I said. You can create your own custom subclass of `View`, override methods like `onDraw()`, and directly render your image to a `Canvas`, rather than creating a bunch of bitmaps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the response, could you make an example with my code? I'm really lost.. cant figure it out. I'm very new to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a ***custom view*** instead of trying to made the same every time with `getView`
- Use a ***ViewHolder***